# AngularJS button text is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Example taken from Apress book.

MyAppModule.js

```
// Create the module
angular.module('myAppModule', []);

// configure the module with a controller
angular.module('myAppModule').controller('myProductDetailCtrl', function ($scope) {

        // Hide colors by default
        $scope.isHidden = true;

        // a function, placed into the scope, which
        // can toggle the value of the isHidden variable
        $scope.showHideColors = function () {
            $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
        }

    }
);
```

I modified it to:

```
// Create the module
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', []);

// configure the module with a controller
myAppModule.controller('myProductDetailCtrl', ['$scope',function ($scope) {

        // Hide colors by default
        $scope.isHidden = true;

        // a function, placed into the scope, which
        // can toggle the value of the isHidden variable
        $scope.showHideColors = function () {
            $scope.isHidden = !$scope.isHidden;
        }

    }
]);
```

I modified this
product-detail.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
<html ng-app="myAppModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myAppModule.js"></script>
    <style>

        body {
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        div {
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color:#ffffff;
        }

        #red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #green {
            background-color: green;
        }

        #blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #purple {
            background-color: purple;
        }

        #gray {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        #olive {
            background-color: olive;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myProductDetailCtrl">

<h2>AngularJS Socks</h2>

<p>Keep warm this winter with our 100% wool, 100% cool, AngularJS socks!</p>

<button ng-click="showHideColors()" type="button">
    {{isHidden ? 'Show Available Colors' : 'Hide Available Colors'}}
</button>

<div id="red" ng-hide="isHidden">Red</div>
<div id="green" ng-hide="isHidden">Green</div>
<div id="blue" ng-hide="isHidden">Blue</div>
<div id="purple" ng-hide="isHidden">Purple</div>
<div id="gray" ng-hide="isHidden">Dark Slate Gray</div>
<div id="olive" ng-hide="isHidden">Olive</div>

</body>
</html>
```

to this:
(moved the ng-app directive)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myAppModule.js"></script>
    <style>

        body {
            font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        div {
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color:#ffffff;
        }

        #red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        #green {
            background-color: green;
        }

        #blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        #purple {
            background-color: purple;
        }

        #gray {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        #olive {
            background-color: olive;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myAppModule"  ng-controller="myProductDetailCtrl">

<h2>AngularJS Socks</h2>

<p>Keep warm this winter with our 100% wool, 100% cool, AngularJS socks!</p>

<button ng-click="showHideColors()" type="button">
    {{isHidden ? 'Show Available Colors' : 'Hide Available Colors'}}
</button>

<div id="red" ng-hide="isHidden">Red</div>
<div id="green" ng-hide="isHidden">Green</div>
<div id="blue" ng-hide="isHidden">Blue</div>
<div id="purple" ng-hide="isHidden">Purple</div>
<div id="gray" ng-hide="isHidden">Dark Slate Gray</div>
<div id="olive" ng-hide="isHidden">Olive</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Button label/text shows:

```
{{isHidden ? 'Show Available Colors' : 'Hide Available Colors'}}
```

and pressing it does nothing.

Comment: any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
myAppModule.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Comment: Are you sure that the `angular.js` file is loading correctly?

Comment: I don't know. I have angular.min.js file on the same folder with myAppModule.js file

Comment: But you are referencing `angular.js` **not** the `min.js`.

Comment: You are right. Haven't noticed. Just copied it from the Apress book source code. My bad. I'll report this Errata and give you the credit :). Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an old version of `AngularJS`.

Here is the working version in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/h7L1qreb/1/).

Comment: I have the latest one. I downloaded 1.3.13 earlier today.

Comment: can you put your example on JSFiddle or compare with the working version that I posted?

Comment: If I put my code in JSFiddle it worked, but it runs on 1.2.1 version.